# Complicated Sub-query - is this possible?

Tags: mysql, select, many-to-many, subquery, sql-like

I've got 2 tables: one stores tags, the other stores articles. There's a mode "Get articles by tag", which basically takes all articles, tagged "x". In my articles table I use a filed, called `Tags`, that stores data in such pattern 'tag1, tag2, tag3, ...'.

So I want to get everything work by just a single query like that:

```
SELECT *, 
       (SELECT tagname 
          FROM `tags_table` 
         WHERE tagurn LIKE 'x') as TAGNAME 
  FROM `articles_table` 
 WHERE (Tags LIKE 'TAGNAME,%' OR Tags LIKE '%, TAGNAME' ... and so on)
```

I don't know if it's even possible, but I'd really like to use a single query (with a sub-query) instead of two different.

Answer (score 6):

This is the wrong way to store a many-to-many relationship in a database.

You should have a schema like:

```
     articles: [PK] article_id, ... (should have no reference to tags)
         tags: [PK] tag_id, tag_name, ...
articles_tags: [FK] article_id, [FK] tag_id
```

*`[PK]` = primary key, `[FK]` = foreign key*

Where `articles_tags` is a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). Now, you can get all articles with a given tag with (if you know the `tag_id` you won't even need the `JOIN`):

```
    SELECT article_id, ...
      FROM articles_tags
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = articles_tags.tag_id
     WHERE tag_name = 'TAGNAME'
```